# Is app size larger in older Android versions?

Tags: applications

I currently have Android 6.0 Marshmallow. If I install a newer Android version, will the app take less storage on my phone? In other words, does an app carry excess luggage to get it working on older phones?

Comment: That depends. In Google Play Store you developers publish multiple versions of an app for different Android versions. Additionally you can split modern apps based on the CPU type (ABI), language and other factors so that each device needs to download and store only the required parts. This feature is AFAIK available since Android 5.

Comment: @Robert If you are able to confirm which version of Android started allowing those splits, please do let us know. Thanks!